# React.js -- Not Passing Components Correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my code, I am using Redux and the state I am passing from my container, `this.props.mapGenerated.grid`, is a 2D array.

Having said that, I am nesting a loop in order to output `Tiles` from its component but I do not see it being invoked at all.

**container.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import Tiles from '../components/Tiles';

class MapGenerator extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderTiles = this.renderTiles.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){

  }
  renderTiles(cell,row,column){
    <Tiles cell={cell} row={row} column={column} />

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <svg width="500" height="500">
        {this.props.mapGenerated.grid.map( (row,rowIndex) =>{
          row.map( (cell, colIndex) =>{
            this.renderTiles(cell,rowIndex, colIndex)
          })
        })}
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you forgot a return in renderTiles

Comment: I've tried wrapping it with the return keyword but I still do not see being invoked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `return` in the `map` and the function `renderTiles()`,

Try this code. Hope this helps!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import Tiles from '../components/Tiles';

class MapGenerator extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderTiles = this.renderTiles.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){

  }
  renderTiles(cell,row,column){
    return <Tiles cell={cell} row={row} column={column} />

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <svg width="500" height="500">
        {this.props.mapGenerated.grid.map( (row,rowIndex) =>{
          return row.map( (cell, colIndex) =>{
            return this.renderTiles(cell,rowIndex, colIndex)
          })
        })}
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked that in ES6, if you use `( )` instead of `{ }` when wrapping your `map` function, you dont need `return` keyword

Answer (score 0):

use return keyword

```
return row.map( (cell, colIndex) =>{
   this.renderTiles(cell,rowIndex, colIndex)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you passing the prototypes ? I am expecting something below the class like

```
MapGenerator.propTypes = {
  mapGenerated: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Another thing is `renderTiles` as notted by the user above, i think it should return the value. Moreover, try and -print your props in the console before the mapping and see if it has a value. In the render method before the return .

```
console.log(this.props.mapGenerated.grid);
```

Does it return your values ?

**Update**

Try java script [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) 
Ecmascript

```
::this.renderTiles
```

Comment: Yes, `console.log(this.props.mapGenerated.grid)` is valid. In fact, when I call the callback, `this.renderTiles(cell,rowIndex,colIndex` and console log inside the callback function, I see it i being passed.

For some reason when I invoke `<Tiles />` in it, it doesnt return anything, despite as someone suggested when I wrap it with the keyword `return`